# Short story involving teens raised to be replacement bodies

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story I read in a magazine in the 90's.

It focused on a boy who is getting ready to graduate high school (I think it may have been a boarding school?) And while initially the adults are enthusiastic about what he can do after school they suddenly all drop off and act weird after looking in his file. Then he finds out he is a replacement body and is taken off and it ends.

I believe perhaps all of these students had the same birthday?

For some reason I tend to think it may have been in *Playboy*, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Playboy did occassionally give some authors carte blanche to write Sci-fi stories. Pretty sure Authur C. Clarke even wrote one for Playboy once.

Comment: Reminds me of the YA novel [*House of the Scorpion,*](http://www.amazon.com/The-House-Scorpion-Nancy-Farmer/dp/0689852231) by Nancy Farmer.

Comment: The idea of raising children for future body/organ harvesting has been used in many stories (Duncan's 'Strings' for example), but this mostly reminds me of [Never Let Me Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Never_Let_Me_Go_%28novel%29), which was later done into a movie.  I don't recall it ever being in short-story format, tho.

Comment: @SFruggerio, "Occasionally give some authors carte blanche to write Sci-fi stories"? Given several Nebula and Hugo award winners have published frequently in Playboy, that every major Clarke novel was first serialized in the magazine and that renowned short SF author Fredric Brown was its chief fiction editor for years I think you are being a little sarcastic there.
As to the original story, might i suggest looking up the basis work for the movie NEVER LET ME GO

Comment: @Covertwalrus adding to your point, as I recall, Playboy was reknown for paying the highest rate per word for stories, period.